# how to specify available items in the listview?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-listview, android-scrollview

I created Fragment View for my app, with ListView and View.

In that listView I have number of items say 30 [ but only ten visible at a time] when focus on it shows scroll..

how to show item availability by default, that is if I m last in the listView, top of list has ^ to show items are in up.. like the same for the vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just check the count of the items and then say if count > 10 then there are more items to view -

like in my case where cur is the cursor, you can use array count etc.

```
   if (cur.getCount() >10)

{
//do stuff here
}
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: scrollView.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);